# Unable to sort array of strings with qsort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of strings using qsort. My program will take an integer value then allow input of strings depending on what the integer value was, then allow another integer value to be inputted as well as that many strings. I then try to use qsort to sort the inputted strings in descending order, however it just prints the order in which they were inputted.

```
int sort(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char* s_a = *(char**)a;
    char* s_b = *(char**)b;
    return (strlen(s_b) - strlen(s_a));
}

int main(void)
{

    char input[100];
    int n;
    int j;
    int l;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char** strings = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        scanf("%s", input);
        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
        strcpy(strings[i], input);

    }

    int m;
    scanf("%d", &m);
    strings = realloc(strings, (n + m) * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = n; i < m + n; i++) {

        scanf("%s", input);
        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
        strcpy(strings[i], input);

    }


    int k = m + n;

    qsort(strings, l, 100, sort);
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        printf("%s", strings[j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `qsort(strings, l, 100, sort);` --> `qsort(strings, k, sizeof(*strings), sort);`

Comment: Aha such a simple mistake, thank you very much!

Comment: Just wondering if there's anything I could do to make my code more efficient?

Comment: If you turn on all warnings, like this ` -Wall` when compiling, you would have seen a warning like this: `warning: ‘l’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: Note that the difference between two return values from `strlen()` is always an unsigned quantity because `strlen()` returns a `size_t` value.  If the second string is longer than the first, you're officially treading on thin ice because of undefined behaviour when the large positive value is converted to an `int`.  You may get away with it, but it isn't guaranteed.